# Rails 3 - Cheddargetter or Chargify Sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, e-commerce, payment-gateway

If you have implemented recurring billing solution w/API of Cheddargetter or Chargify, can you help a nuby out w/ your sample code or highlight key points what to do in MVC in rails 3?

I have been studying their API doc, yet still struggling.  Your kind help is greatly appreciated.  Linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this wrapper for cheddar getter: https://github.com/hashrocket/mousetrap

This should get you started: http://support.cheddargetter.com/discussions/problems/155-cheddargetter-beginner

Comment: David, thanks. I studied your code and still a bit over my head (since i never implemented api and payment before) need more specific MVC instruction for a nuby.

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a look too:

https://github.com/expectedbehavior/cheddargetter_client_ruby